# How to delete only the child entities in a many-to-many relation with extra columns in JPA and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

here I have my problem.
I have a entity Component where it has some fathers (padres) and sons (hijos). So it's a many2many relation. But as it has to have a quantity column it is a many2one and many2one relation to an extra entity.
The problem cames when I try to delete one component. I have tried many thing and I have achieved to possible solutions, deleting everything or not deleting anything.
What I want is ONLY DELETING the SONS (hijos).

This is the main entity class:

```
public class Componente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "identificador", nullable = false)
    private String identificador;
    @Column(name = "descripcion", nullable = false)
    private String descripcion;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "componente", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) //cuando haces put devuelve
    private Set<ComponenteRelacion> padres = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "padre", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) //cuando haces put devuelve
    private Set<ComponenteRelacion> hijos = new HashSet<>();


    public void addPadre(Componente componente, int cantidad) {
        ComponenteRelacion componenteRelacion = new ComponenteRelacion(this, componente, cantidad);
        padres.add(componenteRelacion);
    }

    public void removePadre(Componente componente) {
        for (Iterator<ComponenteRelacion> iterator = padres.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ComponenteRelacion userRole = iterator.next();
            if (userRole.getComponente().equals(this) && userRole.getPadre().equals(componente)) {
                iterator.remove();
                userRole.setPadre(null);
                userRole.setComponente(null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the relation class:

```
public class ComponenteRelacion {

    public ComponenteRelacion(Componente componente, Componente padre, int cantidad) {
        this.id = new ComponenteRelacionPK(componente.getId(), padre.getId());
        this.componente = componente;
        this.padre = padre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private ComponenteRelacionPK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("componenteId")
    private Componente componente;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("padreId")
    private Componente padre;

    protected int cantidad;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(componente, padre);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ComponenteRelacion other = (ComponenteRelacion) obj;
        return Objects.equals(padre, other.padre) && Objects.equals(componente, other.componente);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id+"-"+cantidad;
    }
}
```

And this is how I load the data:

```
 Componente componente = new Componente();
        componente.setDescripcion("PADRE");
        componente.setIdentificador("PADRE");
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);

        componente = new Componente();
        componente.setIdentificador("A");
        componente.setDescripcion("A");
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);
        componente.addPadre(componenteService.findByDescripcion("PADRE"), 1);
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);

        componente = new Componente();
        componente.setIdentificador("B");
        componente.setDescripcion("B");
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);
        componente.addPadre(componenteService.findByDescripcion("A"), 1);
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);

        componente = new Componente();
        componente.setIdentificador("C");
        componente.setDescripcion("C");
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);
        componente.addPadre(componenteService.findByDescripcion("B"), 1);
        componenteService.saveComponente(componente);

        System.out.println("EMPEZANDO EL DELETE");
        componenteService.deleteComponente(3L);
```

I have tried with all the cascade types and it is not working.
I have been looking the hibernate logs but it is not working.

Comment: It's not clear what you want and what behavior you are seeing. The code, when removing a Component, is setup so that all ComponenteRelacion instances that reference it will be deleted. If you want further depth of the object graph removed, you'll have to put the cascade delete option on other relationships.

Comment: @Chris Hello Cris, what I want is that when I do deleteComponente(3L) deletes the componente with id 3 and all his componentes hijos. Also the relations with hijos and with his fathers.

Comment: Right, so check the latest part of my comment - you don't have cascade settings on those relationships, which is why they are not being deleted. You did it for part of the graph, but not the part that isn't being removed.

Comment: Also note, JPA requires you to set both sides of a bidirectional relationship. This code is only setting the Componente's Padre collection/relationship (so the ComponenteRelacion entity will have both references set, but all hijos collections will be empty unless the Componente instances are refreshed from the database). You should, within addPadre, make sure calls something like "componente.getHijos().add(componenteRelacion);" to keep it in synch with what is in the DB. If the collection is empty, JPA won't see anything there to remove